# How to replace basic SliderBar with images

Tags: qml, slider

i want to custom a **Slider** with an image for the **SlideBar**, an image for the **SliderDot** and display vertically.
also i want to control a table content with the Slider and the **stepsize** to be one row of the **tableView**
any ideas?

Comment: Did you check https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-slider ?

Comment: yes, but that is for Controls 2.12, i want to use this imports import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Comment: I think you'll find there to be only just minor differences between various 2.x and, likewise, 1.x versions. So you can attempt to replace 2.12 with 2.5 and so forth. Having said that, it is important to always state the version of Qt version as part of your question because that significantly changes the answer. The latest Qt5.x versions are on Qt5.15.x which are LTS then there are the Qt6.x versions, so, honestly, you should be on a supported Qt version.